# Do Django templates implement short-circuiting for logical expressions?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Suppose I have the following in my Django template:

```
{% if a != None and a.b > 5 %}
```

Can I be certain that `a.b > 5` won't be evaluated if `a` is None?

IE: Does python's short-circuiting while evaluating logical expressions kick in in Django templates?

Comment: Try it? This should take two seconds to test.

Comment: They do short-circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior doesn't appear to be specified in the official documentation, but the presence of [bug #13373](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13373) implies they do, except in v1.2 beta.

The fix made in [commit `fef0d25bdc`](https://github.com/django/django/commit/fef0d25bdc) still seems to be present in the [current version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/smartif.py) of `smartif.py`, so it's fairly safe to assume it still works.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will short-circuit. I have taken a peek into the source of Django 1.9.2 and think I found [the relevant code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/smartif.py#L93).

```
# Operator precedence follows Python.
# NB - we can get slightly more accurate syntax error messages by not using the
# same object for '==' and '='.
# We defer variable evaluation to the lambda to ensure that terms are
# lazily evaluated using Python's boolean parsing logic.
OPERATORS = {
    'or': infix(6, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) or y.eval(context)),
    'and': infix(7, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) and y.eval(context)),
    'not': prefix(8, lambda context, x: not x.eval(context)),
    'in': infix(9, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) in y.eval(context)),
    'not in': infix(9, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) not in y.eval(context)),
    # This should be removed in Django 1.10:
    '=': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) == y.eval(context)),
    '==': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) == y.eval(context)),
    '!=': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) != y.eval(context)),
    '>': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) > y.eval(context)),
    '>=': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) >= y.eval(context)),
    '<': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) < y.eval(context)),
    '<=': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) <= y.eval(context)),
}
```

The [`IfParser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/smartif.py#L149)  class is used to evaluate the condition in an `if` block expression. Above, it is seen to use the built-in `and` functionality.

An example evidencing this may use a view like:

```
def printer(): print 'called'

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response({'log': printer})
```

The following templates will and will not print "called" to the console, respectively.

```
{% if True and log %}  # prints "called"
{% if False and log %} # does not print "called"
```